# fileHelpers common engine and attribute setting

Tags: c#

I am using common engine to convert the data table I have to csv

How do I set an attribute on that particular column. Note I dont have a class for the records since I dont need one
 CommonEngine.DataTableToCsv(dt, "date.csv", ',');

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload for this method that allows you to pass in CsvOptions where you can specify the delimiter and other things like "DateFormat" [CsvOptions](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.CsvOptions.html)

Bit late but hope it helps someone.